# Is it possible to change the snitch from Property back to simplesnitch?

Tags: cassandra

Going from SimpleSnitch to PropertyFileSnitch or Gossiping i succeded but the reversed process not.

Ended in this point :

`Cannot start node if snitch's data center (datacenter1) differs from previous data center (DC3). Please fix the snitch configuration, decommission and rebootstrap this node or use the flag -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true.`

Tryed to insert into cassandra-env.sh the -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true also the -Dcassandra.ignore_rack=true
Even changed in a desperate attempt the cassandra-topology.properties to look like ip=datacenter1:rack1

All futile.

Is it possible to go back from PropertyFileSnitch to SimpleSnitch (data inserted via property and network topology ) or am i hunting ghosts?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: why would you make that change (I am curious)? The simple snitch (and SimpleStrategy for that matter) is more of a snitch for demos and testing than anything you would actually want to use in production. That said I thought cassandra.ignore_dc=true would work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

cassandra.ignore_dc=true would work:

https://github.com/apache/cassandra/blob/e6168672bc421f0d0f90dd45bf3a991be578b3dc/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/service/StartupChecks.java#L317

Make sure in your `cassandra-env.sh` you set it in the jvm opts. In the last line of the file set:

```
JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ignore_dc=true"
```

Can check its set via `cat /proc/<cassanda pid>/cmdline`. If using deb should be able to do something like

```
cat /proc/`cat /var/run/cassandra.pid`/cmdline
```

or `sudo service cassandra status`

Comment: It also asks for the ```JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ignore_rack=true"```

Comment: I don't understand. What asks?

Comment: When i tried to restart the server,after adding your line in cassandra-env.sh, checked the log and saw that it spawns new error : "Cannot start node if snitch's rack....". So i had to set also that line : JVM_OPTS="$JVM_OPTS -Dcassandra.ignore_rack=true" to ignore the rack.